# VC's Element not accessible from applicationWillResignActive

Tags: ios, swift, appdelegate

I have

`var vc = MenuVC()` in `AppDelegate`

and inside

`applicationWillResignActive` I have: `vc.waitCancelButtonTapped(self)`

Then inside

`MenuVC()` method `waitCancelButtonTapped`

I have a bunch of code which all works good but when it comes to

`spinner.stopAnimating()` or `waitView.hidden = true`

it crashes with error.

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

What am I missing?

Comment: Did you load the `MenuVC` (I'm assuming VC means `UIViewController`)?

Comment: yes VC means ViewController. What do you mean if I loaded it?

Comment: Did you display the VC to the user or access VC.view in any way? If not, all IBOutlet will not be initialized.

Comment: Yes, I am pressing home button when it is displaying the spinner and waitView on the screen. But it looks like, immediately after pressing home button, these views become inaccessible.

Comment: Can you post the code for `MenuVC`.